# ssl with postgresql 12

Tags: linux, postgresql, ssl

I tried following the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ssl-tcp.html) for the same.
It says postgres.conf will have service.crt for ssl_cert_file, but it has /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem 
and now I can't proceed with it.

Any insight or tutorial will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Change the parameter `ssl_cert_file` to point to your server certificate and `ssl_key_file` to the private key that belongs to it.

If the private key requires a pass-phrase, you also have to set `ssl_passphrase_command` appropriately.

To validate client certificates, put the certification authority certificate in `ssl_ca_file`.